# Do we need the [gun] tag on the Main Site?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

I was looking through the tags today and I found the tag [gun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gun). The first thing that comes to mind is that it is using singular whereas other non-meta tags normally use the plural form.

The second thing is that I remember one of the first discussions on Meta where I was involved:

[Specialized tags for weapons](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4644/specialized-tags-for-weapons)

The consensus seems to be pretty clear that we currently don't want specialized tags for weapons. The [highest voted answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4646/28789) interestingly even mentions [guns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guns) as a bad example, which is obviously different from the existing one because the author of the answer assumed all tags use the plural form.

At the same time the author mentions that "guns" and "swords" could be special cases. But seeing as there is currently no tag for "guns" and no tag for "swords", while the tag "gun" only has 7 questions this doesn't seem to be necessary.

I think we should burninate the tag. What does the rest of the community think?

As a side note I think this is probably a case of a user creating a tag who was not familiar with the guidelines for creating a tag. It might be a good idea to think about whether we want to [replace “create tags” with “suggest new tag”](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/replace-create-tags-with-suggest-new-tag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for showing the community consensus of not wanting specialized tags for weapons.

Furthermore, the evidence shows that the tag was likely mis-created and was basically only used by fairly new users (of the 7 questions, 6 were used by sub 1k rep users, and the last (and oldest question posted with that tag) was used by a ~3k user).

As there were less than 10 questions tagged with "gun", I have gone and taken the liberty of burninating the tag already. It literally took less than 30 seconds.